# Difficulties in style.css to turn mobile responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I have a css built in wordpress but it somehow is not mobile responsive. This is the site I am working on http://jcicitylady.org.hk/

Attached in the link is the style.css code.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/20875480/

Sorry for a bit long of the code. But I was like really have no idea how should I correct it to make the theme become mobile responsive. Therefore, I would like to know if anyone can help to teach me how to make it become mobile responsive?

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the working link of your Wordpress site.! We need more code

Comment: Do you mean the website I am working on? I have edited the question and attach the link.

Comment: you haven't coded your website for mobile devices.! The code is not responsive. Therefore it's rendering like this on devices.! Try this [artcile on responsive development](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is any use of `@media` queries which define how a tag should react depending on what the screen size is. This is ultimately what makes the page responsive. 
This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) contains more information on it.